# Why does Format reject procedure address arguments starting with XE4

Tags: delphi

Consider this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure Foo;
begin
end;

type
  TProcedure = procedure;

const
  FooConst: TProcedure = Foo;

var
  FooVar: TProcedure = Foo;
  P: Pointer;

{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}

begin
  P := @Foo;
  Writeln(Format('%p', [P]));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@FooConst]));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@FooVar]));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@Foo]));
  Readln;
end.
```

This program compiles and runs on XE3 and produces the following output:

```
00419FB8
00419FB8
00419FB8
00419FB8
```

On XE4 and later the program fails to compile, with error messages on both of these lines:

```
Writeln(Format('%p', [@FooConst]));
Writeln(Format('%p', [@FooVar]));
```

```
[dcc32 Error] E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Format' that can be called
with these arguments
```

On XE4, XE5 and XE6, the program compiles when `$TYPEDADDRESS` is switched off. On XE7, the program fails to compile irrespective of the setting of `$TYPEDADDRESS`.

Is this a compiler bug? Or am I using incorrect syntax to obtain the address of a procedure?

Comment: `Addr(FooConst)` and `Addr(FooVar)`works in XE6. [System.Addr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Addr) is unaffected by the $T directive. Don't have XE7 at hand right now.

Comment: @LURD `Addr(...)` compiles and run correctly in XE7 too. Which is odd and points finger at compiler bug. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, `Pointer(@FooConst)` works as well in XE6 and XE7.

Comment: @LURD Yes, I've observed that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is a compiler bug and have submitted a QC report: [QC#127814](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=127814).

As a work around you can use either of the following:

1. Use `addr()` rather than the `@` operator.
2. Cast `@FooVar` or `@FooConst` to `Pointer`, e.g. `Pointer(@FooVar)`.

Comment: FWIW I don't really like answering and then accepting my own answer when there are other answers, but I'm afraid that I don't agree with @aleroot's analysis, and I really do believe that what I have written above is accurate.

Comment: One should note that both workarounds hides the purpose of having `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}`, but this is the best one can do until the bug is fixed.

Comment: @LURD `@` is odd when acting on procedures and procedure vars because oit is designed to yield untyped pointer

Comment: From [The @ Operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#The_.40_Operator), `If X is a variable, @X returns the address of X. (Special rules apply when X is a procedural variable; see "Procedural Types in Statements and Expressions" in Data Types, Variables, and Constants.) The type of @X is Pointer if the default {$T} compiler directive is in effect. In the {$T+} state, @X is of type ^T, where T is the type of X (this distinction is important for assignment compatibility, see Assignment-compatibility).`

Comment: @LURD yes, it's that other doc that is referred to that counts here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Procedural_Types

Answer (score 1):

I think that the behaviour of the new compiler XE7 is more consistent with the specification and the error need to be shown in this case, since the `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}` enforce the `@` operator to return a typed pointer and the Format function instead gets as input an untyped generic pointer.

Since the the purpose of the `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}` is encouraging careful use of pointers, catching at compile time unsafe pointer assignments, it is right that if the function expects a generic untyped pointer(*and in this case make sense because the function purpose is to print the address of it - so no need to have  typed pointer to retrieve its address*), the compiler will catch an error in the case of a typed pointer is passed, the behaviour is consistent with the specification.

I think that in this case the right way to go(based on the documentation) would be :

```
  Writeln(Format('%p', [Addr(FooConst)]));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [Addr(FooVar)]));
```

since the `Addr` function always returns an untyped Pointer that is what the `Format` with `%p` expects and needs.

What I assume is that in previous versions the compiler, in a case like this one, used to perform an automatic cast : `Pointer(@FooConst)` , but it doesn't make too much sense because of the `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}` directive .

Comment: But in your case it is Not a function but a new type that refer to a function ...

Comment: That's right. But in which case how come I can pass `@D` as an argument to `Format` where D is a typed constant or variable of type `Integer` or `Double` or `string` or `record` etc? Your argument should apply there too.

Comment: What you also seem to have neglected is that in XE7, the program yields compiler errors for both `TYPEDADDRESS` settings. I suggest you read that part of the question again. I know it's a little tricky because I'm talking about lots of different compilers behaviours all in one question.

Comment: If the error come even with TYPEDADDRESS OFF we should open an incident in QC Embarcadero because it could not be anything else that a bug this time ...

Comment: It should work with or without TYPEDADDRESS, just as it does for any other type.

Comment: I mean to say that your assertion that Format cannot accept typed parameters is not born out by fact.