# Why is PDWord not ^DWORD?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

This program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

procedure Foo(P: PDWORD);
begin
end;

procedure Bar;
var
  dw: DWORD;
begin
  Foo(@dw);
end;

begin
end.
```

compiles in XE3, but does not in XE4, XE5, XE6 and XE7. The error is at

```
Foo(@dw);
```

```
[dcc32 Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'PDWORD' and 'Pointer'
```

This feels odd. So, after a bit of digging it seems that the issue is down to the definition of `PDWORD`. One might naturally think that it would be:

```
PDWORD = ^DWORD;
```

and indeed that is the case in XE3. In later versions we find this:

```
// Note: Not ^DWORD yet
PDWORD = ^CppULongInt;
```

Odd. So, what is `CppULongInt`?

```
CppULongInt = type LongWord; 
{$EXTERNALSYM CppULongInt 'unsigned long'} 
{$OBJTYPENAME CppULongInt 'Bul' 'Gm'}
```

Then looking at the declaration for `DWORD` we find:

```
//NOTE: DWORD should really be CppULongInt
DWORD = LongWord;
```

So, `CppULongInt` and `DWORD` are different types. Hence the compilation error.

What's going on here? What is the purpose of `CppULongInt`? Why do the RTL designers appear to want to alias `DWORD` to `CppULongInt`. Is this change related to the x64 Windows C++ compiler based on LLVM? Am I the only person in the world that uses `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}`?

Note, that last question is rhetorical.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I'm looking at XE7 and giving it a run out on my codebase which currently builds on XE3. Things are not going as smoothly as one might hope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815970/why-does-format-reject-procedure-address-arguments-starting-with-xe4

Comment: Is DWORD still an alias to LongWord?

Comment: @Sertac Ah, switched off computer. Late here now. Can't check now. `CppULongInt = type LongWord` defines new type rather than alias.

Comment: I noticed. Pretty weird to define a pointer of a type to a type other than its own.

Comment: @Sertac The very name CppULongInt gives me the fear. It's as if they forgot that Delphi exists. Which is I suppose a change from the normal state of affairs when it goes in the other direction.

Comment: In XE6 System.Types: `//NOTE: DWORD should really be CppULongInt
  DWORD = LongWord;`.

Comment: IOW, "I know a PDWORD does not point to a DWORD, but I don't care".

Comment: [QC Report #:  115307](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=115307)

Comment: Another thing that makes me not want our company to migrate from XE2 to XE6.

Comment: @Sertac *I know a PDWORD does not point to a DWORD, but I don't care, because I use $TYPEDADDRESS OFF!*

Comment: The documentation says it's should be an alias to LongWord (aka Cardinal) heck even the wrong code is statet there... So it's clearly something that at Embarcadero someone didn't notice the difference between an alias and a new type...

Comment: @mrabat `DWORD` is an alias to `LongWord`. See LURD's comment above.

Comment: @mrabat probably meant CppULongint, which is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.CppULongInt) to be an alias.

Comment: I could not resist :) - http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2014/09/13/why-pdword-is-not-a-pointer-to-dword/

Comment: So, possible answers to *"Why is PDWord not ^DWORD?"* - There's a developer who cannot tell a type from an alias. - There's a developer who doesn't have the slightest idea about the relation between `PDWORD` and `DWORD`. - @Serge's theory involving more developers, which amounts to "there's a development team who doesn't give a f..".

Comment: To me, it looks a like a simple oversight.

Comment: @Rudy *Note: Not ^DWORD yet* seems quite intentional

Comment: The use of "yet" seems to indicate that was supposed to become `^DWORD` (again), but was typedef-ed as `^CppULongint` for some reason, and that this was simply not changed back to the original

Comment: This is fixed in XE8. http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115307.

Answer (score 5):

(Refering to [Why `PDWORD` is not a pointer to `DWORD`](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2014/09/13/why-pdword-is-not-a-pointer-to-dword/).) It looks someone at Embarcadero didn't read [the relevant Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#DWORD_PTR):

- `DWORD` is explicitly defined as a *32* bit `unsigned integer`, thereby in Delphi it should be an `UInt32`.
- `PDWORD` is defined as a pointer to a `DWORD`, thereby in Delphi it should be `PDWORD = ^DWORD`.
- It's `DWORD_PTR` (which is not a `PDWORD`!) that is defined as an `ULONG_PTR`, and the latter changes in size depending on the *platform* (32 or 64 bit), not the compiler definition of an `unsigned long`.

One reason may be they are attempting to use `DWORD` and other Windows datatypes on non Windows platforms, and are trying to keep them compatible. If so, in this case they failed and introduced a bug, because the definitions used won't work properly in Windows.

Comment: You are referring to Serg's blog article here. Certainly C++ `long` is platform dependent. I'm asking why `PDWORD` isn't `^DWORD`, and also what `CppULongInt` is. Emba certainly aren't trying to use `DWORD` away from Windows.

Comment: Actually the Windows header file defines DWORD as an alias to unsigned long. The Windows data model in turn says that long is 32 bits. C++ long is implementation defined. For any implementation on Windows this all mandates 32 bit long on that platform.

Comment: Why Embarcardero defined it that way only Embarcadero knows. My guess is that it attampted to keep it compatible with different platforms/architectures, or the translation was made directly from the header files without taking into account the documentation.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said in my first comment. The `DWORD` type is declared in `System.Types` which is x-plat. Quite how `DWORD` could have meaning away from Windows is beyond me though.