# Compare procedural pointers in XE6

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, delphi-xe6

The following sample program compiled in Delphi XE2 and earlier:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}

type
  TMyProc = procedure(Dummy: Integer);

procedure MyProcA(Dummy: Integer);
begin
  //
end;

var
  MyProcVar: TMyProc;

function Test: Boolean;
begin
  Result := @MyProcVar = @MyProcA;
end;

begin
  if Test then
    Writeln('OK');
end.
```

It doesn't compile anymore in XE6 with error

> [dcc32 Fehler] Project1.dpr(22): E2008 Inkompatible Typen

which translates to

> [dcc32 error] Project1.dpr(22): E2008 Incompatible types

If I switch to `{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}` or `Addr(MyProcVar) = Addr(MyProcA)` it compiles. Is this a bug in XE6 or in XE2 which maybe shouldn't have compiled it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan had a similar question couple of days ago. See if I can find it. Here it is: [Why does Format reject procedure address arguments starting with XE4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25815970/576719).

Comment: Thanks, @LURD! I guess it's the same bug. I guess my issue would be more appropriate for an eventual bug report as it only touches the simplest language features, no `array of const` etc.

Comment: `This question has been asked before and already has an answer` - to be correct there is no answer to the question so far. The answer should be like that - "it is a compiler bug; see the bug report #xxxx"

Comment: I've been reluctant to answer my own question but it looks like I need to if nobody else can supply the needed answer. Which is as @user24 says

Comment: OK, I did that thing, added answer and QC report

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. @MyProcA is a pointer to procedure, while @MyProcVar is a pointer to TMyProc. Try declaring `PMyProcVar = ^TMyProc;` and replace the test with `PMyProcVar = @MyProcA`. This gives `[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(43): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMyProc' and 'Procedure'`.

Comment: Then again, both boils down to the same conclusion. See [Procedural Types in Statements and Expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#Procedural_Types_in_Statements_and_Expressions). `@MyProcVar` should return an untyped pointer regardless of the `TypedAddress` setting. See [The @ Operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#The_.40_Operator) that says special rules apply to procedure variables.